# Flutter : NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'nom' was called on null. Receiver; null Tried calling: nom

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, dart

I try to assign value to the attributes of the PanierModel but I receive this error on picture

NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'nom' was called on null. Receiver; null Tried calling: nom

```
class _TestSQFLITEState extends State<TestSQFLITE> {

  DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper();

  PanierModel _panier;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    setState(() {
       _panier.nom  = _panier.nom  == null ? "Arduino" : "";

    });

    void _ajouterPanier() async {
      int result;
      result = await helper.insertPanier(_panier);
      if(result != 0)
        print('STATUS Panier Save Successfully');
    }

return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(_panier.nom , style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          Text("Abibou", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: _ajouterPanier, 
       child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white,),),
);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't initialized _panier yet, can you share all code ?

Comment: Where did you initialise `_panier` ? Also your code looks messed up above, please edit and update it.

Comment: Please check, I just published the complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not initialising your _panier and that's why you get the error because _panier.nom is called on null as _panier is null and null object doesn't have any attributes. You have to do the following:

```
PanierModel _panier = PanierModel(); //now _panier is not null anymore
```